# Remove active class from toggled element on other element click

Tags: jquery

In the menu that you see in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/osnq30bg/1/, if i click on triangle from Item 2 (that has childrens), the childrens show.

If i click on triangle from Item 3, the childrens show.

The problem is that i do not manage to close the childrens from Item 1 which are already active. Tried all sort of solutions regarding toggle but in this particular case i miss something to make it happen?

```
<header class="main" id="siteheader">
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link active"><span></span> Menu</a>
    <nav id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="level-1">
            <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Item 2</a><span class="has-subnav">&#x25BC;</span>
                <ul class="wide level-2">
                    <li><a href="">Child Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Child Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Child Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Item 3</a><span class="has-subnav">&#x25BC;</span>
                <ul class="level-2">
                    <li><a href="">Child Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Child Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

// Multi-Toggle Navigation
$(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');
        var $menu = $('#menu'),
            $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
            $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });

});

// Remove "Active" Class from Menu on Resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewportWidth > 925) {
            $("#menu").removeClass("active");
        }
});


a.menu-link {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link span {
  border-bottom: solid 3px #000;
  border-top: double 10px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 5px -3px 0;
  width: 30px;
}

.menu-link:hover span { border-color: #666; }

.menu, .menu > ul, .menu > ul ul {
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu.active {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin: 1em 0 1em -12px;
  max-height: 55em;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.js .menu > ul ul.active {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 55em;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu > ul { padding: 0; }

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.04em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span.has-subnav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  top: 0;
}
 @media screen and (max-width:800px) {

.menu,  .menu > ul ul {
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.menu li li a { padding-left: 50px; }

.menu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.menu li li:last-child a { border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8; }

.menu li:hover { background: #EDEDED; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {

nav {
  border-top: 3px solid #00578b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a4d05e;
}

a.menu-link { display: none; }

.js .menu,  .js .menu > ul ul {
  max-height: none;
  overflow: visible;
}

.js .menu > ul li:hover > ul { display: flex; }

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 44px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu span.has-subnav { display: none; }

.menu li a:hover { color: rgb(164,208,94); }

.menu li li a:hover {
  background: rgba(164,208,94,0.1);
  color: #000;
}

.menu ul ul {
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px rgba(164,208,94,1);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 5px 5px;
  border-top: solid 2px transparent;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 43px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.chrome .js .menu > ul ul { top: 43px; }

.menu ul ul.wide { width: 300px; }

.menu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(164,208,94,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu > ul ul li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }

.menu ul ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nowhere in your `$menuTrigger.click` function where you "tell" others dropdowns to close, actually. You can do it by closing each opened one before opening the clicked one (you have to test if it's not the one you clicked too, or else you can't close anymore, the clicked item being closed before being toggled):

```
$menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $menuTrigger.each(function(){
        if(!$this.is($(this)) && $(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

see [forked updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/48nqpkmu/)

EDIT:

To close your menu dropdowns when menu is closed you can add a similar `each` in `$menulink.click`;

```
$menulink.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
    $menu.toggleClass('active');
    $menuTrigger.each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Then, to close the menu when clicked outside, you can add such event to `body` and `html` (we have to add an id to the burger span to be able to detect if not clicked on it too).:

```
var $menuBurger = $('#menu-burger');

$('body, html').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    if(!target.is($menulink) && !target.is($menu) && !target.is($menuTrigger) && !target.is($menuBurger)){
        $menulink.removeClass('active');
        $menu.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48nqpkmu/3/)

Comment: Working perfect. May i ask why you updated your post? The first one seems to work as well. One more thing, if possible, can we close the whole menu if we click anywere on the page (outside the menu)?  https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/osnq30bg/2/

Comment: I updated the first post because you couldn't close an opened dropdown anymore by clicking on its arrow (for the reason i added in brackets). The other thing should be another question actually, but i'll give a try

Comment: Have noticed one slight issue. If i open a submenu and than i close the whole menu from burger icon, than click again on burger will show the expanded submenu. Can we prevent this behaviour? Meaning that click on burger icon resets all active classes from the childrens so the submenus are closed?

Comment: @Adyyda Edited the post to consider these issues

Comment: @Adyyda sorry my bad, i used `originalTarget` which works on firefox but is not standard, updated with `target`, should work now

Comment: This is rather strange. The updated demo work. But, if i copy the code from the jsfiddle the menu will stop work, it will not exapnd and jumps a little. The same thing happens if i copy the code from bellow EDIT in this page.  I tried and copied the code in another jsfiddle and there it works as well. Very strange.

Comment: I have made a html page in which i added the code from jsfiddle + jquerry 1.8.3 (since that is in the site) and all the code that you supplied works just fine so the issue is in the site. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: you're welcome! consider accepting the answer it it helped ;)